# How do I run/display mutliple graphics methods at the same time?

Tags: java, graphics

I am using very basic Java Graphics and am trying to display multiple graphics methods at the same time. In other words, I would like to overlap them.

Currently, when it runs, it displays one graphic for a brief moment before disappearing and displaying the other.

Is there any way to fix this?

Here is the runner for my graphics.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GraphicsRunnerCopy extends JFrame
{
private static final int WIDTH = 800;
private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

public GraphicsRunnerCopy(int x,int y,int z,int n)
{
  super("My Frame");
  setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
  getContentPane().add(new Graphic(x,y,z,n));
  setVisible(true);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     GraphicsRunnerCopy run = new GraphicsRunnerCopy(3,3,1,20); //I want this to display at
     GraphicsRunnerCopy run2 = new GraphicsRunnerCopy(0,0,5,4); //the same time as this

  }
}
```

Within my object that is being displayed by the runner, I am using code like below.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Canvas;

class Graphic extends Canvas
{
private int x,y,z,n;

public Graphic(int xa, ya, za, na)
{
  x = xa;
  y = ya;
  z = za;
  n = na;

  setSize(800,600);
  setBackground(Color.WHITE);       
  setVisible(true);
}

public void paint( Graphics window )
{
  Color tan = new Color(185, 133, 91);    

  window.setColor(tan);
  window.fillRect((x*n+20/z), (y*n+20/z), (320/z), (320/z)); //base

 }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split out the logical code and data from the component code:

- Only one class should do all the drawing (this is the component code), and this is the class that has the `public void paint(Graphics g)` method
- The drawing entities will be *logical* classes, meaning that these classes shouldn't extend Canvas or any other *component* type of class.
- These drawing classes, say called Drawing, can also have their own paint method, but they will be called by the component class.
- The component class should be allowed to hold multiple drawing entities, say in an ArrayList,
- And in the component class's painting method, iterate through the list, drawing each Drawing object.

For example, if I were doing this using Swing (because AWT is even more out of date than Swing), I'd do something like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GuiFun extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 600;
    private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.WHITE;
    private List<Draw> draws = new ArrayList<>();

    public GuiFun() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));
        setBackground(BACKGROUND);
    }

    public void addDraw(Draw draw) {
        draws.add(draw);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Draw draw : draws) {
            draw.myPaint(g);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GuiFun guiFun = new GuiFun();
        guiFun.addDraw(new Draw(3, 3, 1, 20));
        guiFun.addDraw(new Draw(0, 0, 5, 4));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GuiFun");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(guiFun);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Draw {

    private static final Color TAN = new Color(185, 133, 91);
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;
    private int n;

    public Draw(int x, int y, int z, int n) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.n = n;
    }

    public void myPaint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(TAN);
        g.fillRect((x * n + 20 / z), (y * n + 20 / z), (320 / z), (320 / z));
    }
}
```